Solving simultaneous partial differential equations to find the electric field of a current-carrying straight wire

As an engineer ($j$ is the imaginary number), I am working to derive the electric field for a particular structure. I have ended up with the following pair of differential equations that I need to solve.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{\partial r \partial z} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{{\partial r}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_z
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{\partial z \partial r} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial z}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_r
$$
For context/reference, the following is a copy of the notes I am making in parallel to the derivation:

Attenuation of Current in a Current-Carrying Wire
When running current down a wire in CST Studio Suite, the current seems to be exponentially attenuated with distance along the wire. This seems to be related to frequency. These notes report on attempts to theoretically define the electromagnetic fields so that it can be compared to simulation results.
Here we aim to couple Faraday's Law and Ampere's Law to derive the electromagnetic fields in/around the wire, assuming the use of Cylindrical Coordinates.
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}
$$
The current flows through in the $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$-direction. The electric field is directed in the $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ directions and the magnetic field is directed in the $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$-direction. Quantitatively, the fields are given by:
$$
\mathbf{E} =
\begin{pmatrix}
E_r \\
0 \\
E_z
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathbf{H} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
H \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
When we apply the cylindrical curl to $\mathbf{E}$, we get:
$$
\nabla \times
\begin{pmatrix}
E_r \\[10pt]
0 \\[10pt]
E_z
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial \phi} \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial E_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial r} \\[10pt]
-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial E_r}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial \phi} = 0$:
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} =
\left( \frac{\partial E_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
$$
When we apply the cylindrical curl to $\mathbf{H}$, we get:
$$
\nabla \times
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\[10pt]
H \\[10pt]
0
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{\partial H}{\partial z} \\[10pt]
0 \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial H}{\partial r}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{H} =
\left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
$$
Substituting $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}$ into Faraday's Law and $\nabla \times \mathbf{H}$ into Ampere's Law, we get the following differential equations:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial E_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
=
-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
\mathbf{J} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}
$$
The fields are sinusoidal so we can write differential equations as phasors:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
=
-j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{B}}
$$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
\tilde{\mathbf{J}} + j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{D}}
$$
Now, there are two cases of Ampere's Law. We will consider both subsequently:

Outside the wire, there is no conduction current ($\mathbf{J} = 0$), so the equation simplifies to:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{D}}
$$

Inside the wire, there is conduction current ($\textbf{J} \neq 0$), so the equation doesn't change:


$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
\tilde{\mathbf{J}} + j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{D}}
$$
Outside the Wire:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
=
-j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{B}}
$$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \left( \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial z} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
j\omega \tilde{\mathbf{D}}
$$
First of all, find an expression for $\tilde{H}$:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r} \right)\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
=
-j\omega\tilde{B}\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}
$$
$$
\tilde{B} = 
\frac{j}{\omega}\left(\frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r}\right)
$$
$$
\tilde{H} = 
\frac{j}{\omega\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r}\right)
$$
Substitute into the differential equation by Faraday's Law:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(\frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r}\right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
- \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{\partial \tilde{E}_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \tilde{E}_z}{\partial r}\right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
=
\omega^2\mu\varepsilon\tilde{\mathbf{E}}
$$
Forming second-order differential equations and expanding $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{\partial r\partial z} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{{\partial r}^2}\right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}
+
\left(\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{\partial z\partial r} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial z}^2}\right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}
\equiv
\omega^2\mu\varepsilon\tilde{E}_z\mathbf{\hat{z}} + \omega^2\mu\varepsilon\tilde{E}_r\mathbf{\hat{r}}
$$
Setting the vector components equal to each other to form two differential equations:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{\partial r \partial z} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{{\partial r}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_z
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{\partial z \partial r} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial z}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_r
$$
EDIT:
I am not sure if the following is correct (can one just factor out $\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial r}^2}$, like that), but here we go:
Writing the first equation in terms of $\tilde{E}_z$:
$$
    \tilde{E}_z =
    \frac{
        \frac{
            \partial^2 \tilde{E}_r
        }{
            \partial r \partial z
        }
    }{
        \frac{
            \partial^2
        }{
            {\partial r}^2
        }
        +
        \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon
    }
$$
Substituting this into the second equation and rearranging:
$$
    \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial r}^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial z}^2} + \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_r = 0
$$
or
$$
    \nabla^2 \tilde{E}_r + \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_r = 0
$$
This differential equation now needs to be solved.

My attempt (hope this help):
We have:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{\partial r \partial z} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{{\partial r}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_z
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_z}{\partial z \partial r} - \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{E}_r}{{\partial z}^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \tilde{E}_r
$$
These equations significant case second-order PDEs which are chances to solve them directly with analytic methods are very small. The interaction between $E_r$ and $E_z$ because of which it is hard to use the split-up section unambiguously.
Consider the explanation of the problem, and one of the most important steps is to consider the problem to be of the AD as a propagation along the z-axis. This is the essence of understanding the way the measured value declines as it is developed in the AD. Let's assume that the traveling wave solution is
$$
\tilde{E}_r(r,z) = E_{r0}(r)e^{-\gamma z} \\
\tilde{E}_z(r,z) = E_{z0}(r)e^{-\gamma z}
$$
Here, $\gamma$ is the propagation constant (maybe the complex number), and the real part is the attenuation. Applying this to the original PDEs, the derivative with respect to z becomes scalar multiplication by -γ. So, we get the new equations:
$$
-\gamma \frac{d E_{r0}}{dr} - \frac{d^2 E_{z0}}{dr^2} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon E_{z0}
$$
$$
-\gamma \frac{d E_{z0}}{dr} - \gamma^2 E_{r0} = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon E_{r0}
$$
These are now ordinary differential equations in r only, but they remain coupled. Such common equations are still to be dealt with very seriously.
The first step involved in the process is the attempt to uncouple the equations. The second one can be simply reformulated to express $E_{r0}$ in terms of $E_{z0}$ which, after being substituted into the first equation, will provide us with the new ordinary differential equation in $E_{z0}$ only. Difficult solution of this equation will require perhaps the use of the numerical methods.
In essence, the vital objective here is to find $\gamma$ (the propagation constant), as the real part is the attenuation constant and the imaginary part is the phase constant. If you can specify $\gamma$, the issue will be successfully solved.
Numerical methods may be concerning for the boundary conditions at the wire surface and the far-field behavior. In typical settings, these coupled ODEs quickly become cumbersome, and usually computational methods are the most effective responses. Keep in mind also the skin effect, as higher frequencies indicate necessary consideration of non-uniform current across wires.

Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to see where this gets me. However, I have a question. What is AD?

Look at my edited question. I have managed to form a single differential equation now, but I am not sure if what I did is valid mathematics (can I just factor out $\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial r}^2}$, like that?)
